# Neo4j query for taking max of a column based on group by of another column

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I want to convert the below SQL query to Neo4j query:

```
select max(col1) from screens GROUP BY col2
```

I want to get a group of similar col2 and then extract max col2 from it.
I am unable to find group by in neo4j, some of the posts are using Count(*) instead of group by in neo4j, but that does not fits in my problem. The above query is working fine in SQL but I need it for neo4j.

Any idea how it can be done?
Thanks

Comment: What is your neo4j Schema, what is col1? You are missing a lot of details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use group by function in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028038/how-can-i-use-group-by-function-in-neo4j)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL equivalent of Max/Group By in cypher is doing a collect, unwind then get the max value.

```
 MATCH (n: Screens)
 WITH collect(n.col1) as coll_n1, n.col2 as col2
 UNWIND coll_n1 as col1
 WITH col2, max(col1) as max_col1  
 RETURN col2, max_col1
```

is equivalent to

```
 select col2, max(col1) 
 from screens 
 GROUP BY col2
```

References:

[UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/):
[WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/):

Comment: Good answer. Adding links to documentation for [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) and [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/).